# How to convert a cupy.ndarray to a scalar?

Tags: python-3.x, cupy

I'm working with CuPy at the moment. I've noticed something that seems to be a bug, but I'm not sure.

I've noticed that if I use certain math functions, they result in the wrong shape. For example:

if I do this using numpy it returns a scalar with no shape. As it should.

```
s8 = numpy.abs(2)
```

However if I use CuPy:

```
s8 = cupy.abs(2)
```

It results in `cupy.ndarray`. When evaluated with `s8.shape`, it returns `()`

The frustrating part is trying to convert cupy.ndarray into a scalar with no shape. I've tried using:
`cupy.Squeeze(s8)` and `s8.item()` to return just the scalar. In both cases it returns the value but retains the shape. I've also tried using `float(s8)` and `int(s8)`. Both of which return the appropriate value type, but the array still remains.

Any thoughts on how to convert this from a cupy.ndarray to a scalar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a known behavior in CuPy and is not a bug:
https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/difference.html#reduction-methods

Unlike in NumPy (which makes the distinction between scalars and 0-d arrays), all scalars in CuPy are 0-d arrays, otherwise it would unavoidably lead to a data transfer by converting them to Python scalars, which compromises the performance.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "How to convert a cupy.ndarray to a scalar?"

Comment: and the link seems to be broken

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 a working link is https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/user_guide/difference.html#reduction-methods but the answer is to explicitly cast the value, e.g. use `int(cupy.abs(2))` or `float(cupy.abs(2.0))`.

Also `.item()` is used in some code, e.g.:

```
s8 = cupy.abs(2)
s8 = s8.item()
```